# 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

when I issue following code in python where myfun is the name of my function, B is Panda data frame:

```
myfun(B,10)
```

it gives error at this line in the function

```
A=(data.loc[ii]>=A1) & (data.loc[ii]<A2)
```

where B and data are the same and A1 and A2 are numbers.
The error is as follow:

```
'the label [0] is not in the [index]'
```

I read everything in your website it does not apply to my case. as nobody has explained what this error is talking about.

Can anyone tell where possibly I can have a problem and how I can fix it?
What does even mean to say label [0] is not in [index]? what is label[0] in my case.

Comment: It means you have no 0 in your index of the data DataFrame

Comment: The `ii` variable in your code should iterate over the elements of the dataframe index, not over the integers. The `loc` allows you to get access to some rows/cols of dataframe based on the labels. Thus ii as a label should be existing in `dataframe.index`. Most probably you should do `for ii in data.index:` then your code for filtering by `A1` and `A2`.  (This is assumption based on the error and that piece of the code that you provided). It would be good if you could give more information.

Comment: Show us the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `pandas` documentation:

> DataFrame.loc
>
> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.
>   .loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array.
>   Allowed inputs are:
>
> - A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer position along the
>     index).
> - A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'].
> - A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.
> - A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].
> - A callable function with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame or Panel) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of
>     the above)

Since I guess that `ii` is of type integer, you need to use `df.iloc` instead:

```
A = (data.iloc[ii] >= A1) & (data.iloc[ii] < A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs when your index doesn't start with 0. I reset my index using the code below which fixed the error.

```
train_df = train_df.reset_index()
```

This does not directly address the issue described in the question, but wanted to leave this here for reference in case anyone comes across the same error in future.